# How to pull up a UIKeyboard without a UITextField or UITextView?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uikeyboard

I'm currently developing an OpenGL ES game for the iPhone and iPod touch.

I was wondering how I can easily pull up the UIKeyboard? 
**Is there an *official, documented* possibility to pull up a UIKeyboard without using a UITextField of UITextView?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display the iPhone/iPad keyboard over a full screen OpenGL ES app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253477/how-to-display-the-iphone-ipad-keyboard-over-a-full-screen-opengl-es-app)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not "officially" possible - you can't access the UIKeyboard object at all while staying within Apple's guidelines.

Creating an invisible UITextField, then calling `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` would do the job - you could even subclass UITextField first, then override the delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` to redirect the text input to where you want it to go.

Comment: See more up-to-date answer from @john using 3.2+ API

Comment: __This answer is now wrong__. [See here for an example of how to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253477/how-to-display-the-iphone-ipad-keyboard-over-a-full-screen-opengl-es-app)

Answer (score 19):

If you subclass UIResponder, and declare the UIKeyInput protocol, the keyboard will appear when you become the firstResponder.

See the [UIKeyInput protocol here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

One thing that tripped me up is that you'll need to override the canBecomeFirstResponder message.

Comment: Only `UIView` subclasses, not just _any_ UIResponder subclass. I tried to make my AppDelegate (a UIResponder) subclass, show a keyboard and failed.

Comment: After subclass of `UIView`, what's the different between an `UITextfield` ? they are all have to be added to the screen, then become the first responder, show the keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed possible. I had myself struggled a lot with this. UIKeyInput protocol can be used to pull a keyboard without using a UITextField or UITextView. However it is only available in iOS 3.2 and above. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.ioslearner.com/uikeyinput-displaying-keyboard-iphone-uitextfield-uitextview/) on that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I displayed the keyboard without any visible UITextField by positioning my textfield's frame out of the visible screen:

```
#define TEXT_FRAME                 -50,-50,0,0

self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(TEXT_FRAME)];
```

When I set the "first responder" the keyboard becomes visible without any visible input area:

```
// show the keyboard    
[self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

I later dropped the idea. However, I don't know its conformance to the Apple guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UIKeyboard shows some code that looks like it should work.

Comment: I don't think UIKeyboard is officially exposed in the SDK, so perhaps to be "legal" you have to use a hidden UITextField.

Comment: @David - So it's not possible then?

Comment: The code you posted does not work. While it may be valid, the compiler will let you know that you can't access the `UIKeyboard` class.