# It is possible to show keyboard without using UITextField and UITextView iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uitextview, uikeyboard

I am working in iPhone messaging based app.

I want to show keyboard with keyboard `inputAccessoryView` in keyboard without using `UITextView` and `UITextField`. It is possible to do this? Please any one help me on this.

Thanks in advance. Looking forward your help. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Because i don't want the `UITextField`/`UITextView` and the control to be in `UITextView`/`UITextField`. I am going to add `inputAccessoryView` on the keyboard is `UITextView`. when the user touches the `UITextview` in the keyboard `inputView` the actual process will be continue.

Comment: See the `- showKeyboard:animated:` method [in this class.](https://github.com/H2CO3/FileTransfer/blob/master/FTViewController.m)

Comment: i don't think so.. you can have a hidden or a textField with zero alpha.. and programmatically handle the firstResponder..

Comment: I think you can't but you can make text field invisible.

Answer (score 31):

For anyone, who wants to show keyboard without `UITextField`/`UITextView` for some reasons, could easily extend some view, which requires text input by implementing `UIKeyInput` protocol and `canBecomeFirstResponder` method.

Comment: And if you override `@property (nullable, readwrite, strong) UIView *inputAccessoryView;` in the new class you can assign an `inputAccessoryView` to it too.

Comment: Your control that implements `UIKeyInput` can also implement `UITextInputTraits` if you want to customize the keyboard :)

Answer (score 20):

See the documentation for doing that here:

[Simple Text Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW8)

All you need to do is have your view implement `UIKeyInput` and call `[inputView becomeFirstResponder]` when the view is touched. Your view also needs to implement `canBecomeFirstResponder` and return YES.

[Sample code from the iOS documentation which does this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleTextInput/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010633)

Answer (score 12):

Make a View, Label or what ever to conform to UIKeyInput. In this case a UIView

***Sub class a UIView:***

```
import UIKit

class KeyInputView: UIView {
   var _inputView: UIView?

   override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
   override var canResignFirstResponder: Bool { return true }

   override var inputView: UIView? {
       set { _inputView = newValue }
       get { return _inputView }
   }
}

// MARK: - UIKeyInput
//Modify if need more functionality
extension KeyInputView: UIKeyInput {
    var hasText: Bool { return false }
    func insertText(_ text: String) {}
    func deleteBackward() {}
}
```

***Setup your View, in this case with a picker (in viewDidLoad or where ever)***

```
let languangePicker = UIPickerView()
languangePicker.dataSource = self
languangePicker.delegate = self
keyInputView.inputView = languangePicker
```

***To show:***

```
keyInputView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

***To hide:***

```
keyInputView.resignFirstResponder()
```

Set picker data, from datasource (compiler force u to do it)

Grab data picker events from delegate

Answer (score 4):

#### In xcode simulator:

Sometimes the keyboard wont show because the software keyboard is off. Go to hardware -> Keyboard -> toggle keyboard

Answer (score 2):

You can try the answers on these other SO posts:

- [Use the system keyboard without a UITextView or UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933389/use-the-system-keyboard-without-a-uitextview-or-uitextfield)
- [iphone keyboard without textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472258/iphone-keyboard-without-textview)

You can also try this:

```
UIKeyboard *keyboard = [[[UIKeyboard alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f,          contentRect.size.height - 216.0f, contentRect.size.width, 216.0f)] autorelease];
[keyboard setReturnKeyEnabled:NO];
[keyboard setTapDelegate:editingTextView];
[inputView addSubview:keyboard];
```

Comment: Friend it is showing "error: Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'keyboard'" error. Could you please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @Gopinath you should handle syntax errors on your own at the very least

Comment: The last link seems to be spam.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a small utility file that can call a Keyboard with a textfield on a button touch !

https://github.com/havocked/TZKeyboardPop