# how to solve Use of undeclared identifier 'UIKeyboard' error?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uikeyboard

Am trying to show UIKeyboard without using `UITextView` and `UITextField`. Am following the below source code to show the Keyboard in my app.

```
 UIKeyboard *keyboard = [[[UIKeyboard alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 220.0f, 320.0f, 216.0f)] autorelease];
[keyboard setReturnKeyEnabled:NO];
[keyboard setTapDelegate:editingTextView];
```

but the code showing below errors,

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'UIKeyboard'
Use of undeclared identifier 'keyboard'
```

Anyone please help to solve this error? and please tell me this is the right way to show keyboard without using `UITextView` and `UITextField`?

Comment: Because you declared it forcefully.

Comment: @VakulSaini could you please tell me clearly? thanks.

Comment: Was it(UIKeyboard) seen in intelligence ?

Comment: what is the reason to show keyboard, when you dont want user to input anything?

Comment: @waheeda please see this question asked by me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995514/how-to-keep-keyboard-visible-in-uitextview-non-editable-iphone-app

Comment: @VakulSaini then how can i show keyboard in my app without using UITextView or UITextField? any suggestions please...

Comment: @Gopinath - I gave you answer about your `error` you cant write which is not in intelligence. Have you declared an object of your name in xcode ????? Obviously it will give you an `error`.

Comment: @VakulSaini yes, but when i used Google to show keyboard without UITextView they gave this code so am trying. so if you could you please guide me to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @VakulSaini please see this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005969/it-is-possible-to-show-keyboard-without-using-uitextfield-and-uitextview-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIKeyInput` delegate.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIKeyInput>
```

And in your `ViewController.m` class. `return YES;` to `canBecomeFirstResponder:`

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES; 
}
```

It will show you `keyboard`. But Where you write if there is no `UITextView` or `UITextField`.
Well for writing on `UIView` see this logics - [UIKeyInput- Displaying keyboard in iPhone without UITextField or UITextView](http://www.ioslearner.com/uikeyinput-displaying-keyboard-iphone-uitextfield-uitextview/)

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. Now i can see the keyboard. I won't allow the user to enter any texts. I want to add an UIToolbar in this keyboard as InputAccessoryView. I will try this and let you know friend.