# How to programmatically show soft keyboard on Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I tried this code to display the keyboard, but it didn't work:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.EndEditing(false);
```

Is there a way for Xamarin iOS to display the soft keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , we would need a control which could receive input like **UITextField** and **UITextView** .

The way to show soft keyboard programmatically is pretty simple , just call `becomeFirstResponder` method .

What's more , `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.EndEditing(false)` should be working as well , you can have a try .

---

If you don't want to add a **UITextField/UITextView** , as a workaround you could customize a view and implementet `UIKeyInput` protocol(`canBecomeFirstResponder` method).

Please refer to the details below

[It is possible to show keyboard without using UITextField and UITextView iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005969/it-is-possible-to-show-keyboard-without-using-uitextfield-and-uitextview-iphone).

---

> To be clear , if you don't have **UITextField/UITextView** or custom view implementing `UIKeyInput` protocol on currect viewcontroller, it is **impossible** to show the soft keyboard programmatically .