# how to popup default iphone keyboard on a button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-4.2

Hi
When we click on a UITextField or UITextView, a default keyboard pops up from the bottom of iphone screen. I want iphone keyboard to appear on a button click, and then handle the keys as typed on keyboard... How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was searching my problem, and came across the following stackoverflow link which answers my question

[How to pull up a UIKeyboard without a UITextField or UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376120/how-to-pull-up-a-uikeyboard-without-a-uitextfield-or-uitextview)

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Add touchupinside event on button and call becomeFirstResponder method for textview or textfield it will call pop up keyboard.
see the following code-

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicktoModalView:(id)sender{
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls go through this

[iphone keyboard without textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472258/iphone-keyboard-without-textview)

Hope this helps