# Manipulate the iPhones UIKeyboard as a "regular" UIView

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

Im struggling a bit with the UIkeyboard, I have a datePicker, IntervalPicker some custom pickers and a few other UI elements that live in the same part of the screen as the keyboard.

I have build a factory class that places these on the screen depending on the state of the app, I control animation and layering myself and here the problem starts. It all works for the elements I mentioned, but the Keyboard I can't seem to control to the same extend.

I would like to instantiate a keyboardView, place it on the screen with an alpha of 0 inside an UIView and when Im good and ready, fade and animate it in.

It seems I can only get a Keyboard on the screen if I build a textField and then set it as firstResponder, this results in the keyboard animating in as expected, but it completely breaks my factory approach.

Hope it makes sense:) thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard isn't a regular view. You have to stop trying to use it like one. 
[How to pull up a UIKeyboard without a UITextField or UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376120/how-to-pull-up-a-uikeyboard-without-a-uitextfield-or-uitextview)
Don't fight with the SDK, make the sdk your friend.

Comment: Ahh the old "be one with the SDK" :)

I had contemplated using a dummy textField and then juggling the views appropriately, but thought I would visit the brain trust first.

Thank you Kenny!

Comment: Who are we to blow against the wind, my friend?