# How can i show Keyboard while open Mailcomposer?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I want to show keyboard when mail composer open without take any action.i mean when mail composer open automatically keyboard should display.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but have you tried `[mailComposer becomeFirstResponder];`? I don't think it'll work, but it's worth a shot...

Comment: i have tried it but not working if you have any other idea please.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376120/how-to-pull-up-a-uikeyboard-without-a-uitextfield-or-uitextview/1389780#1389780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible as far as I know.  You might be able to traverse the views of the `mailComposer` to find the appropriate text field but that is a risky thing to do and liable to break.

Plus it *might* get your app rejected.  Although it's not exactly clear.  From the [MFMailComposeViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.